# Why does `$session->set()` have two arguments?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to **Symfony2**. I was going through the documentation, reading about sessions. Strange thing I've noticed that a session in **Symfony2** can hold two seperate strings like this:

`$session->set('foo', 'bar');`

I was hoping the documentation would explain this but all it says is:

```
// store an attribute for reuse during a later user request
```

Could someone explain this to me, please?

Comment: actually you are simply, doing: $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar'; you can set and array of strings. http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html#method_set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$session->set('foo', 'bar');` will set the attribute named `foo` to value `bar`.

You can read more about session management in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html).

Comment: Exactly. Symfony2 provides a very powerful wrapper for PHP's sessions. Being a wrapper means in the end it *will* be translated to something like `$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';`. It just makes it easier to work with them, as well as being more secure.

Comment: ye just have to get jus to these new Symfony2 conventions. thank you

Comment: would you mind upvoting my question...as you can see am poor in them xd